# where is the trigger point when using sequence in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm studying kotlin in official site.
I understand that the sequence has two type operation(intermediate, terminal).
And the intermediate operation is triggered when the terminal operation is called.
What I want to know is that the trigger point when the terminal operation is called.
I deep dive into the code but couldn't find the source code.
Where is the trigger source code?

```
public fun <T> Sequence<T>.toList(): List<T> {
    return this.toMutableList().optimizeReadOnlyList()
}

public fun <T> Sequence<T>.toMutableList(): MutableList<T> {
    return toCollection(ArrayList<T>())
}

public fun <T, C : MutableCollection<in T>> Sequence<T>.toCollection(destination: C): C {
    for (item in this) {
        destination.add(item)
    }
    return destination
}
```

*updated*

```
fun testSequence(){
    val words = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".split(" ")
//convert the List to a Sequence
    val wordsSequence = words.asSequence()

    val lengthsSequence = wordsSequence.filter { println("filter: $it"); it.length > 3 }
        .map { println("length: ${it.length}"); it.length }
        .take(4)

    println("Lengths of first 4 words longer than 3 chars")
    
// terminal operation: obtaining the result as a List
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    println(lengthsSequence.toList())
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what "intermediate" and "terminal" are, but I fear your priorities may be misaligned. The point of `Sequence` is that it's a lazy list. That's all. Exactly *how* that's implemented is, generally speaking, the Kotlin stdlib's problem, not yours. If your code relies on the sequence being forced at a particular moment, then your code is exceedingly brittle and needs to be refactored or needs to use a different data structure entirely.

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger point"? What are you looking for, exactly?

Comment: I think this question is perfectly clear -- it's when the lazy collection is processed to produce a nonlazy result.  In every case, it's when the backing Sequence is iterated.

Comment: There's not usually a single ‘trigger point’ where the entire sequence is evaluated. Instead, it evaluates only as much as is needed, at the the point where it's needed. For example, the terminal operation `firstOrNull()` will evaluate the first item in the sequence (doing the minimum of intermediate operations needed to get it); if that doesn't match, it will evaluate the next one, stopping as soon as it has a match (and leaving the rest of the sequence untouched).

Comment: If you're talking about this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sequences.html#sequence-operations what it's saying is that a *sequence* is *lazy* - it doesn't do anything when you declare it, it's just a blueprint for producing values. You have to run a *terminal* operation on it that actually runs the sequence and returns a result. If you take a sequence and chain *another sequence-producing function* onto the end of it, that's not *terminal* because it's just extending the blueprint, if you like. So those extra sequence operations are called *intermediate*. *Terminal* means the end of the seq

Comment: Thank you all, guys. what I mean for the trigger point is that the intermediate operation is processed when the terminal operation(toList()) is called. I updated the source and I sleep the thread for 2 seconds. the intermediate operation is called after 2 seconds. So I thought there is some trigger point in toList()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might help to see that the for loop in `toCollection` is translated to:

```
when(val $iterator = this.iterator()) {
    else -> while ($iterator.hasNext()) {
                val item = __iterator.next()
                destination.add(item)
            }
```

(See the [spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/statements.html#for-loop-statements) for more details on how for loops work)

The key thing here is that this includes a call to `iterator`, and a call to `next` on that iterator. What these calls actually *does* will depend on what intermediate operations you have called.

For example, let's consider the sequence `listOf(1,2,3).asSequence()`. Looking at the source code for `asSequence`, we can see that the `iterator` for this sequence is just the same iterator as `listOf(1,2,3).iterator()`. (Verifying this has been left as an exercise for the reader)

Therefore, calling `toList()` on this sequence will give you the list `[1,2,3]`.

Now consider `listOf(1,2,3).asSequence().filter { it == 2 }`. `filter` returns a [`FilteringSequence`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/b65c477e68d2e4e3b635d63b7cdc61f41829d472/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Sequences.kt#L157), with its own implementation of `iterator`:

```
public fun <T> Sequence<T>.filter(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Sequence<T> {
    return FilteringSequence(this, true, predicate)
}

...

internal class FilteringSequence<T>(
    private val sequence: Sequence<T>,
    private val sendWhen: Boolean = true,
    private val predicate: (T) -> Boolean
) : Sequence<T> {

    override fun iterator(): Iterator<T> = object : Iterator<T> {
        val iterator = sequence.iterator()
        var nextState: Int = -1 // -1 for unknown, 0 for done, 1 for continue
        var nextItem: T? = null

        private fun calcNext() {
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                val item = iterator.next()
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The important thing here is that in `filter`, `this` is passed to `FilteringSequence`, which becomes `sequence`, and in its implementation of `iterator`, it *uses* `sequence.iterator()`, calling `next` on it, in addition to performing the filtering logic specific to `filter`, of course.

This means that when you do `toList` on `listOf(1,2,3).asSequence().filter { it == 2 }`, and it calls `next` on the filtering sequence's iterator, it will eventually call `next` on the iterator of `listOf(1,2,3)`.

All the intermediate operations are like this. They are all defined in terms of an "upstream" sequence, and they will use the iterator of the "upstream" sequence in their implementation of `iterator`. Therefore, if you have a chain of

```
listOf(1,2,3).asSequence()
    .map { it + 1 }
    .filter { it > 0 }
    .take(5)
    .flatMap { listOf(it, it) }
    .count()
```

You create

1. a `TransformingSequence` with `listOf(1,2,3).asSequence()` being the upstream,
2. a `FilteringSequence` with 1. being the upstream
3. a `TakeSequence` with 2. being the upstream
4. a `FlatteningSequence` with 3. being the upstream

and when `count()` is called, the `next` method of the iterator of the `FlatteningSequence` is called, which in turn calls that of the `TakeSequence`, which in turn calls that of the `FilteringSequence`, and so on... Hence performing the logic of each operation, as those are implemented in the `next` method.

Comment: thanks for your answer. what I mean for the trigger point is that the intermediate operation is processed when the terminal operation(toList()) is called. I updated the source and I sleep the thread for 2 seconds. the intermediate operation is called after 2 seconds. So I thought there is some trigger point in toList(). Can I ask for why the intermediate operation is triggered after 2 seconds when toList() is called?

Comment: @user9628944 “so I thought there is some trigger point in toList()”. Yes indeed. As I said, it is the call to `next` on that iterator, which calls `next` on the iterators of the intermediate operations, which calls your lambdas eventually, as part of their logic.

Comment: I guess you mean the override interator in intermediate operation(filter or and so on) is called when the terminal iterator call the iter.next(), right?

Comment: @user9628944 Yes that is correct. And that is where the mapping, filtering (etc) logic are implemented.

Comment: I understand now, Thank you sweeper.